# Printing First Variable in Awk but Only If It's Less than X

Tags: linux, awk, gnu

I have a file with words and I need to print only the lines that are less than or equal to 4 characters but I'm having trouble with my code. There is other text on the end of the lines but I shortened it for here.

file:

```
John Doe 
Jane Doe
Mark Smith
Abigail Smith
Bill Adams
```

What I want to do is print the names that have less than 4 characters.

What I've tried:

```
awk '$1 <= 4 {print $1}' inputfile
```

What I'm hoping to get:

```
John 
Jane
Mark
Bill
```

So far, I've got nothing. Either it prints out everything, with no length restrictions or it doesn't even print anything at all. Could someone take a look at this and see what they think?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `awk 'length($1) <= 4 {print $1}' inputfile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let understand why

```
awk '$1 <= 4 {print $1}' inputfile
```

gives you whole `inputfile`, `$1 <= 4` is numeric comparison, so this prompt GNU `AWK` to try to convert first column value to numeric value, but what is numeric value of say

```
John
```

? As GNU `AWK` [manual Strings And Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html) put it

> A string is converted to a number by interpreting any numeric prefix
> of the string as numerals(...)Strings that can’t be interpreted as
> valid numbers convert to zero.

Therefore numeric value for `John` from GNU `AWK` point of view is zero.

In order to get desired output you might use `length` function which returns number of characters as follows

```
awk 'length($1)<=4{print $1}' inputfile
```

or alternatively pattern matching from 0 to 4 characters that is

```
awk '$1~/^.{0,4}$/{print $1}' inputfile
```

where `$1~` means check if 1st field match, `.` denotes any character, `{0,4}` from 0 to 4 repetitions, `^` begin of string, `$` end of string (these 2 are required as otherwise it would also match longer string, as they do contain substring `.{0,4}`)

Both codes for inputfile

```
John Doe 
Jane Doe
Mark Smith
Abigail Smith
Bill Adams
```

give output

```
John
Jane
Mark
Bill
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Would be interesting to know which one wins from an efficiency standpoint. I suspect that `length()` would win over the regex parsing -- though both may ultimately do the exact same thing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin There's also `substr($1,5,1) == ""` that'd be interesting in a speed test :-). They're probably all so similar the speed doesn't really matter though and the clarity and portability of `length($1) <= 4` would be the best choice (some older awks don't support RE intervals like `{0,4}`).